# Mutability in Rust: value borrowed after move?

Tags: rust, immutability

I've been writing a small process manager that monitors the state of a few spawned processes and aims to keep them up whenever they get killed. Unfortunately, I seem to be facing mutability issues since I'm unable to alter the contents of a hashmap within a loop.

Here's my implementation:

```rust
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::process::Command;
use std::process::Child;
use std::collections::HashMap;

type AgentMap = HashMap<String, Child>;

fn spawn(name: String, agents: AgentMap) {
    let child = Command::new("python")
        .arg("agent.py")
        .arg(name)
        .spawn()
        .expect("worker failed to start");

    agents.insert(name, child);
}

fn main() {
    let mut agents = AgentMap::new();
    spawn("a1".to_string(), agents);

    loop {
        for (agent, process) in &mut agents {
            let timeout = Duration::from_secs(1);
            sleep(timeout);
            match process.try_wait() {
                Ok(Some(status)) => {
                    println!("Exited with status {}", status);
                    spawn(agent.to_string(), agents);
                },
                Ok(None) => println!("timeout, process is still alive: {}", agent),
                Err(e) => println!("Error waiting: {}", e),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting to be able to loop through the map and replace any faulty agent with a new spawned pid. Unfortunately, the code does not compile and yields:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `agents`
  --> src/main.rs:24:33
   |
20 |     let mut agents = AgentMap::new();
   |         ---------- move occurs because `agents` has type `HashMap<String, Child>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
21 |     spawn("a1".to_string(), agents);
   |                             ------ value moved here
...
24 |         for (agent, process) in &mut agents {
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
   |
note: consider changing this parameter type in function `spawn` to borrow instead if owning the value isn't necessary
```

Comment: `spawn` takes ownership of `agents` and drops it when it returns. But all it needs is a mutable reference to insert something.

Comment: You also can't insert something into a `HashMap` while you're iterating over it, so calling `spawn` again from inside the loop is not going to work.

Comment: No multithreading is necessary and I did not intend to add one. Should I make `agents` a global variable? Would that solve the mutability issue?

Comment: Because main needs to read it only, not mutate it. Only spawn needs to change it. However, if I remove &mut from the loop, it claims that it needs to be mutable.

Comment: @isaactfa I'm replacing the value, not inserting.

Comment: No you're not, I don't know what to tell you. `agents` gets dropped at the end of `spawn` so you can never use it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the loop, the hashmap is borrowed as mutable; your `spawn` function takes ownership of the `agents` parameter (it moves it), which you can't do while holding onto a mutable reference.

My suggestion would be to refactor as follows:

- Have `spawn` return the `Child` and have the caller add it to the `AgentMap`
- Have the inner loop take advantage of your mutable reference to just update the existing entry.

```
// note: using AsRef<str> means you can pass both a String or &str here
// this gets rid of your .to_string() invocations.
fn spawn<S: AsRef<str>>(name: S) -> Child {
    Command::new("python")
        .arg("agent.py")
        .arg(name.as_ref())
        .spawn()
        .expect("worker failed to start")
}

fn main() {
    let mut agents = AgentMap::new();
    agents.insert("a1".into(), spawn("a1"));

    loop {
        for (agent, process) in &mut agents {
            let timeout = Duration::from_secs(1);
            sleep(timeout);
            match process.try_wait() {
                Ok(Some(status)) => {
                    println!("Exited with status {}", status);
                    // process here is a &mut Child; we can just reassign it
                    *process = spawn(agent);
                },
                Ok(None) => println!("timeout, process is still alive: {}", agent),
                Err(e) => println!("Error waiting: {}", e),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was enlightening, thank you John.